# Adding a delay causes the webview to load the redirect url

Tags: android, webview, android-networking

I have a webview and noticed the following:

```
@Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
      try {
         Thread.sleep(5000);  
      } 
      catch (Exception e) {  
      }  

      super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);    
      if(shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)) {    
         webView.loadUrl("javascript:HTML_PARSER.getData" +
                            "(document.forms[0]);");  
         webView.stopLoading();    
      }    
  }
```

This works fine if I comment out the sleep part.
**But** if I execute the sleep part then the webview loads the redirect URL although I go into the if branch due to `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` returning true.
Why is this happening? I don't really understand how webview interals work.
The reason I have this sleep is that I was trying to go through a debugger and added that delay to help me catch the thread. I don't need it of course. But I was surprised at the behaviour

Comment: You should explain better what you're after, but basically WebView uses its own thread "WebCore" unrelated to the UI thread. I don't know what thread calls onPageStarted, can be the UI or WebView's. Just generate an exception and print the stack trace to see whicjh thread you're pausing that interferres with WebView normal behaviour.

Comment: @rupps:What I need is on redirection to not load the view. AFAIK the code I pasted is the way to go, but I was surprised at what happens when introducing that fake/useless/only for debugging the flow delay

Answer (score 0):

`onPageStarted` is just a callback that gets executed after the page has started loading. This means that if the redirect is faster than the time it takes for `onPageStarted` to be called plus the time it takes for your code in it to be executed, then you will not be able to prevent the redirect. Instead, you should overload `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, which is called *before* the redirect, so you can be sure your code is executed.